# How to prove the property of an independent set that is contained in any maximum independent set of graph $G$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let S be an independent set that is contained in any maximum independent set of graph$G = (V,E)$, prove that every maximum independent set of $G$ contains at least one vertex $w \in N(u)-N[S]$ for each child $u \in N(S)$.

Some explanation:

- The *maximum independent set* is an independent set in graph $G$ with the possible largest cardinality.
- For a set $X$ of vertices, let $N(X)$ denote the neighbors of $X$, i.e., the vertices $y \in V-X$ adjacent to a vertex in $X$, and denote $N(X)\cup X$ by $ N[X]$. Specifically, we use $v$ to denote the set $\{v\}$ of a single vertex $v$.
- For an independent set $S$ of $G$, a vertex $u\in N(S)$ is called a *child* of $S$ if it has a unique neighbor $s \in S$(i.e., $|N(u)\cap S|=1$), where $s$ is called the parent of $u$.

I've tried contradiction but failed. Could any one help me with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Proof*.

Choose some child $u\in N(S)$ with its parent $s\in S$. Let $M\subseteq V$ be a maximal independent set. We have $s\in M$ (because $S$ is *by assumption* contained in all maximal independend sets). If no vertex in $N(u)-N[S]$ is in $M$, then we can define the following other maximal independent set by replacing $s$ with $u$:

$$M':=M-s+u.$$

This works because all neigbors of $u$ are either $s$, or in $N(S)$, or in $N(u)-N[S]$, and none of these is in $M'$. However, $M'$ is a maximal independent set without $S\subseteq M'$, in contradiction to the choice of $S$.

$\square$

Maybe the following sketch can help to understand why this exchange is possible. The red vertices (and vertex sets) are part of the independent set. You can see that $u$ has (by assumption) no neighbors in the independent set *except* $s$.

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain why $S \subseteq M$ since I'm new to graph theory and cannot really get something obvious.

Comment: @Mark It was *your* assumption that $S$ is part of any maximal independent set.

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote "matching" instead of "independent set" *everywhere*! I hopefully replaced all mistakes now. Now $I$ would be a better name for the set instead of $M$, but I will leave it because of consistency.